# So I want my robot to go to a desired coordinate on webots

Tags: python, controller, webots

I want my robot to go to a desired coordinate in the world. The only thing I could achieve was to make the robot go foward and turn everytime it runs into an obstacle, but it's all random, and I can't manage to get the robot to go where I want in the world.
Any advice?

```
from controller import Robot, Motor, DistanceSensor, Compass
import time

robot = Robot()


timestep = int(robot.getBasicTimeStep())
MAX_SPEED = 12

distanciaLimite = 0.1 

leftMotor = robot.getDevice('left wheel motor')
rightMotor = robot.getDevice('right wheel motor')

sensorDistancias = []
nombreSensor = [
    'ps0', 'ps1', 'ps2', 'ps3',
    'ps4', 'ps5', 'ps6', 'ps7'
]

izq = True


compassXY = robot.getCompass('compassXY_01')
compassXY.enable(timestep)
compassZ = robot.getCompass('compassZ_01')
compassZ.enable(timestep)

for x in range(8):
    sensorDistancias.append(robot.getDevice(nombreSensor[x]))
    sensorDistancias[x].enable(timestep)

def foward():
   rightMotor.setVelocity(0.7 * MAX_SPEED)
   leftMotor.setVelocity(0.7 * MAX_SPEED)
   rightMotor.setPosition(float('inf'))
   leftMotor.setPosition(float('inf'))

def stop():
   rightMotor.setVelocity(0)
   leftMotor.setVelocity(0)


def turn_right():
   tiempo=0
   tiempoInicial=time.time()
   while robot.step(timestep) != -1:
       rightMotor.setVelocity(-0.5 * MAX_SPEED)
       leftMotor.setVelocity(0.5 * MAX_SPEED)
       rightMotor.setPosition(float('inf'))
       leftMotor.setPosition(float('inf'))
       lecturaSensor = []
       for i in range(8):
        lecturaSensor.append(sensorDistancias[i].getValue())   
       obstaculo = lecturaSensor[4] < distanciaLimite or lecturaSensor[5] < distanciaLimite
       if obstaculo:
           print("asdad")
       else:
           print("no esta aqui")
           return
       tiempoFinal=time.time()
       tiempo=tiempoFinal-tiempoInicial
   return
   

def doblarIzquierda():
   tiempo=0
   tiempoInicial=time.time()
   while robot.step(timestep) != -1:
       leftMotor.setVelocity(-0.5 * MAX_SPEED)
       rightMotor.setVelocity(0.5 * MAX_SPEED)
       leftMotor.setPosition(float('inf'))
       rightMotor.setPosition(float('inf'))
       lecturaSensor = []
       for i in range(8):
        lecturaSensor.append(sensorDistancias[i].getValue())   
       obstaculo = lecturaSensor[2] < distanciaLimite or lecturaSensor[3] < distanciaLimite
       if obstaculo:
           print()
       else:
           return
       tiempoFinal=time.time()
       tiempo=tiempoFinal-tiempoInicial
   return
 
while robot.step(timestep) != -1:
    avanzar()
    XY = compassXY.getValues()
    Z = compassZ.getValues()
    print('compas XY',XY)
    print('compas Z',Z)
    
    
    lecturaSensor = []
    for i in range(8):
        lecturaSensor.append(sensorDistancias[i].getValue())
    #print(lecturaSensor)
    
    
    obstaculo = lecturaSensor[2] < distanciaLimite or lecturaSensor[3] < distanciaLimite
    #print(lecturaSensor[2] ," ", distanciaLimite)
    if obstaculo:
        detener()
        doblarIzquierda()
```

There are some things in spanish cause I speak spanish, if it causes confusion.
I'm using the firebird6 pre made webots robot.
Tried to use compass but didn't work. Please help

Comment: If you want your robot to avoid obstacles and go to the desired location then it is way more complex than a simple Python controller. You need to build a map, localize, global planner, and local planner. The Navigation2 package implements quite robust navigation algorithms:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2

Answer (score 0):

You need gps.h to read the coordinates. You can read the documentation first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).